# How to unittest every class with the same public API in a module with python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a module which parses different file formats like CSV, XLS, HTML, etc.
The different formats contains **exactly the same information**, so I made different classes for parsing different file types. These **classes have the exact same public API**, and obviously have the same base class like this:

```
class BaseParser(object):
    def countTotalValues(self):
        pass

    def countItems(self):
        pass

class CSVParser(BaseParser):
    def __init__(self):
        """Init data, check for errors, etc.."""

    def parse(self):
        """ parses the data and set the result dictionaries like self.values, self.items, etc."""

class XLSParser(BaseParser):
    """ Ha exactly the same public API as CSVParser and set the same inner values. """
    pass
```

Is it a good idea to unit test each of the classes at once with the same values ?
I have been doing this:

```
class TestParserClasses(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instances = []
        for class_, file_ in PARSER_CLASSES:
            self.instances.append(class_(file_))

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.instances
```

and define *every* unit test this way:

```
    def test_count_total_values_without_parameter(self):
        for parser in self.instances:
            parser.parse()
            self.assertEqual(Decimal('9216.84'), parser.countTotalValues())

    def test_count_items_without_parameter(self):
        for parser in self.instances:
            parser.parse()
            self.assertEqual(128, parser.countItems())
```

Is it okay to do this? If yes, how to unit test all of them with the same TestCases at once without

```
    for parser in self.instances:
        parser.parse()
```

So I want to write unittest like this:

```
def test_count_total_values_without_parameter(self):
    self.assertEqual(Decimal('9216.84'), parser.countTotalValues())

def test_count_items_without_parameter(self):
    self.assertEqual(128, parser.countItems())
```

applied to *every* class. Is it possible ?

Comment: This seems more or less similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305985/unit-test-suite-in-python. To answer your question if you should test multiple implementations in one test, I'd say no, because this doesn't give you the info which of them failed and which didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a base `TestCase` and subclassing it for each of the classes you wish to test?

Create it like this, containing your actual test methods, and keep it in a separate module that does not match the test module pattern ([by default, `test*.py`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)) so `unittest` won't discover it:

```
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_count_total_values_without_parameter(self):
        self.assertEqual(Decimal('9216.84'), self.parser.countTotalValues())

    # …more tests…
```

Now, in your test modules, do something like this:

```
import basetest

class TestCSVParser(basetest.BaseTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.parser = CSVParser()

class TestXLSParser(basetest.BaseTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.parser = XLSParser()
```

Comment: This will run three tests: `BaseTestCase.test_count...`, `TestCSVParser.test_count...` and `TestXLSParser.test_count...`, because `BaseTestCase` will be autodetected as testcase in and of itself. The simple remedy is to write a mixin class with the `test_count_...` function and use multiple inheritance from both `unittest.TestCase` and `baseTestCase`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That was why I kept `BaseTestCase` in a separate module. I created a simpler version of this to verify before making my post and `python -m unittest discover` did not pick up the `basetest` module; only the child testcases in the `test` module were picked up, since it matches the `test*.py` glob (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)

Comment: With @UlrichEckhardt's suggestion, this is great !

Comment: I updated the answer with @UlrichEckhardt 's suggestion and will accept it if you approve my edit.

Comment: Sorry zigg, you are right and I should have read the whole thing completely.

Comment: Ulrich I like your solution better, as this would be in the same file,  giving better overview of the test at a first glance, so if you write an answer with it, I accept that.

Comment: @Walkman Thank you, but I would suggest going ahead and writing up your own answer with your preferred solution and accepting it.  There are definitely multiple ways to do this one.

Comment: Actually, I would like to see a solution where everything is in *one* file where `BaseTestCase` subclasses `unittest.TestCase` (because my IDE can help me with autocomplete assert.Equal, etc methods) and the other classes subclasses `BaseTestCase` but `BaseTestCase` will not be tested (as it's not really complete without `setUp`. Can you provide me an example to this ? That would be the perfect solution for me :)